# c program of getting prime factor error i

Tags: c, recursion, function-definition

as you see its a getting prime factors code when  it give outputlast output repat itslef for eg-
input is 15
output should be 3 and 5
but it gives 3 5 and 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int primefac(int n, int count)
{
    while (n > 2)
    {
        int i = 2;
        while (n % count == 0)
        {
            if (count % i == 0 && count == i)
            {
                printf("%d\n", count);
                n = n / count;
                primefac(n, 3);
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n, i = 3, j = 2; // i to get prime factor j is for to check i is prime or not .
                         //n takes input
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n ", 2); // it prints if the no has  factors of 2;
        n = n / 2;          //  it removes factor of from n;
    }
    primefac(n, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug it? If so, what did you find? Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line to examine it as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @kaylum i don't know how to debug any program ??

Answer (score 0):

The inner call of the function in the if statement

```
        if (count % i == 0 && count == i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", count);
            n = n / count;
            primefac(n, 3);
        }
```

outputs 5 and the caller of the function also outputs 5 for the number 15.

Comment: @peter i did not get it can you please elaborate or give the right code.. thankyou